# Setting cookies with responseHeaders (Set-Cookie [] option) are not passing in subsequent API requests in newer Karate versions(1.0.0, 1.0.1)

Tags: karate

I was setting cookies with responseCookies in [karate](https://intuit.github.io/karate/) 0.9.6. But it stopped working when I upgraded karate version to 1.0.0/1.0.1.

I am facing error `ReferenceError: "responseCookies" is not defined` in karate 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 version.

Also, I tried to set cookies with responseHeader Set-Cookie like, `ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"][1] = authcookie_key + "=" + authcookie_value` in newer karate version. I am able to set `responseHeader` cookies but those are not passing in subsequent API request.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there certainly can be bugs, so please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Hopefully this can convince you to try RC versions in the future so that we can avoid these surprises. We spent months on this, see [example](https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1359010765219393538).

Also please read this thread, maybe it is a related issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1526